# SQL for "category" and "item" table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 2 table, 1) Category Table & 2) Item Table

Category table fields are: 1) cat_id 2) cat_name
Item table fields are: 1) cat_id 2) item_id 3) item_name

Category Table Data:

```
|1|Cat A|
|2|Cat B|
|3|Cat C|
```

Item Table Data:

```
|NULL|1|Item 1|
|1|2|Item 2|
|NULL|3|Item 3|
|2|4|Item 4|
|2|5|Item 5|
```

My desired sql out put must be like: (Show all Null category item, but "distinct" item for multiple category"

```
|NULL|1|Item 1|
|1|2|Item 2|
|NULL|3|Item 3|
|2|4|Item 4|
```

And also want to like: (Random if multiple "Item" in same category)

```
|NULL|1|Item 1|
|1|2|Item 2|
|NULL|3|Item 3|
|2|4|Item 4|
```

&

```
|NULL|1|Item 1|
|1|2|Item 2|
|NULL|3|Item 3|
|2|5|Item 5|
```

How I can solve it? Database may "MySQL" and "SQLite" both for mobile end.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cat_id,
       item_id,
       item_name,
       MIN(random())  -- selects a random item from the group
FROM Item
WHERE cat_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cat_id

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,
       item_id,
       item_name,
       NULL
FROM Item
WHERE cat_id IS NULL

ORDER BY item_id;
```